# Adding ng-grid and compass to AngularJs fullstack installation

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, ng-grid, compass

I've installed AngularJS using the fullstack installer here:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

I want to now include ng-grid. How do I go about that? I've already ran `npm install ng-grid` which has copied the files to the node_modules directory. Do I just need to update my index.html file, or do I need to manually update the Grunt file? If so can someone guide me? Can't find anything online that can help me.

I guess the same goes for Compass (I've also already installed Compass using the same method above), as I'd like to initially start using @font-face in my app. I've used Compass several times before but not in this kind of setup...

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**

I've worked out how I should include ng-grid. Wat I should have done is this in the terminal inside my project's dir:

```
bower install ng-grid --save
```

This not only installs the ng-grid files in /bower_components/ but also updates the bower.json in my project's root, so that when I run `grunt serve` it automatically adds the css & js includes in my index.html page. I'm now successfully displaying a table using ng-grid :)

However I've still not worked out how to install compass successfully. I tried `bower install compass-mixins --save-dev` but when I save my _fonts.scss file it produces errors. The error being that it can't find the compass files. Maybe the path is wrong, but I read somewhere that that is what I should put at the top (that or just `@import "compass";`). The paths may also be wrong to my font files, but that's something I'll need to investigate once I can get compass running)

```
@import "compass/functions";
@include font-face("Roboto-Bold", font-files("../assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff", "../assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix", "../assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.ttf", "../assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.svg#LatoBlack"), "../assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot", "normal", "normal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, I don't think you need any installer for ng-grid. The fullstack installer is for setting up your server sided stack. ng-grid.js should (like any other js library you want to pass to the client-browser) be accessible like you would implement (for example) jQuery.

So, assuming your directory structure has a folder called `libs/js`, put something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/js/ui-ng-grid_2.0.11-0/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
```

in the header of your `index.html` and put the source code of ng-grid to that folder. Or use a `cdn server` if you don't want to host the directive on your server.

In no case I would tell anyone from outside where my server sided node modules are stored or would give anyone but me and the server access to them.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments! I have however discovered the way I should be doing the ng-grid part. I'll update my question :)